# How to print more than one result after match in Java

Tags: java

I want to perform a searching to get a result as following and any suggestions let's optimize the code? About the searching in-sensitive and how to get a result easily.

```
Input the keyword for searching the Juice: banana
Searching results: "Banana Juice" "Mango and banana Juice"
```

Here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindJuice {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String[] BooksArray = {
            "Banana Juice",
            "Mango and banana Juice",
            "Apple Juice",
            "Strawberry Juice",
            "Mango Juice"
        };  
    
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);            
        System.out.print("Input the keyword for seaching the book: ");          
        String input = inputScanner.nextLine();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < BooksArray.length; i++) {
            if (BooksArray[i].toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase())){
                System.out.println("Seaching results: " + BooksArray[i]);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No item is found.");
            }
            break;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you think `break;` does?

Comment: Yeah man...get rid of the `break`.

Comment: Hi, if there is no break here, it will show 5 results? Because I just want to show the result I need.

Comment: And does it show 5 results? That's a question you can answer yourself by running your code.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with the below approaches:**

1. **Approach 1**: I have modified your code in which i have created one StringBuilder and append the data if data is found else it will be empty.
2. **Approach 2**: If you are familiar with **Java 8 concepts**, you can try the streams feature as shown below.

***Approach 1:***

**Code:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] BooksArray = {
                "Banana Juice",
                "Mango and banana Juice",
                "Apple Juice",
                "Strawberry Juice",
                "Mango Juice"
        };

        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input the keyword for seaching the book: ");
        String input = inputScanner.nextLine();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < BooksArray.length; i++) {
            if (BooksArray[i].toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase())){
                sb.append(BooksArray[i] + "\n");
            }
        }
        if(sb.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("No item is found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Searching results: " + sb);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Input the keyword for seaching the book: banana
Searching results: Banana Juice
Mango and banana Juice
```

***Approach 2:***

**Using Java8 streams:**

You can achieve the output by using the Java8 `streams` feature in which you can convert the booksArray into streams and `filter` the data based on the input from the user as follows:

**Code:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] booksArray = {
                "Banana Juice",
                "Mango and banana Juice",
                "Apple Juice",
                "Strawberry Juice",
                "Mango Juice"
        };

        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input the keyword for seaching the book: ");
        String input = inputScanner.nextLine();

        List<String> output = Stream.of(booksArray)
                .filter(x -> x.toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Input the keyword for seaching the book: mango
[Mango and banana Juice, Mango Juice]

Input the keyword for seaching the book: banana
[Banana Juice, Mango and banana Juice]
```

Comment: Showing a completly different way to do it doesn't help the OP with their misconceptions.

Comment: @tgdavies Totally agree with you, I have now included both approaches to solve the problem. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code to work as you expected it to work.
it will print all the matching words and if not found any print no result found.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main3 {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String[] BooksArray = {
            "Banana Juice",
            "Mango and banana Juice",
            "Apple Juice",
            "Strawberry Juice",
            "Mango Juice"
        };  
    
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);            
        System.out.print("Input the keyword for seaching the book: ");          
        String input = inputScanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Seaching for: " + input);
        // using a boolean to track if we found the keyword default false.
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < BooksArray.length; i++) {
            if (BooksArray[i].toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase())){
                System.out.println("Found: " + BooksArray[i]);
                found =true;                 // using a boolean to track if we found the keyword default false.
            }
        }
        //if not found print not found.
        if(!found) { 
             System.out.println("No item is found.");
        }
    }
}
```